# mysql stored procedure (with 2 insert) error

Tags: mysql

i have this table

```
create table eveniment( +
       evenimentId bigint not null auto_increment primary key,
       evenimentDenumire varchar(500),
       adresaId int not null);

create table adresa(
       adresaId bigint not null auto_increment primary key,
       localitate varchar(500),
       judet varchar(500),
       codPostal varchar(50),
       strada varchar(500),
       nr varchar(50),
       bl varchar(50),
       ap varchar(5),
       email varchar(500),
       www varchar(500));
```

and this procedure

```
DELIMITER //
drop procedure IF EXISTS insertEveniment;
CREATE PROCEDURE insertEveniment()
BEGIN
DECLARE vAdresaEvenimentId int DEFAULT 0 
insert into adresa(judet,localitate,codPostal,strada,nr,bl,ap,email,www) 
    values('judet','localitate','cod postal','strada','numar','bloc','ap','email','www');
select last_insert_id() into vAdresaEvenimentId;
DECLARE vEvenimentId int DEFAULT 0 
insert into eveniment(evenimentDenumire,adresaId) values('concurs informatic 1',vAdresaEvenimentId);
select last_insert_id() into vEvenimentId;
END //
DELIMITER ;
call insertEveniment();
```

and i get this error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into adresa(judet,localitate,codPostal,strada,nr,bl,ap,email,www) values(' at line 4

if i try the **insert into adresa ...** separately in mysql command i don't get  error , what i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this (tried and it works for me):

```
drop procedure IF EXISTS insertEveniment;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE insertEveniment()
BEGIN
DECLARE vAdresaEvenimentId int DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE vEvenimentId int DEFAULT 0;
insert into adresa(judet,localitate,codPostal,strada,nr,bl,ap,email,www) 
    values('judet','localitate','cod postal','strada','numar','bloc','ap','email','www');
select last_insert_id() into vAdresaEvenimentId;
insert into eveniment(evenimentDenumire,adresaId) values('concurs informatic 1',vAdresaEvenimentId);
select last_insert_id() into vEvenimentId;
END //
DELIMITER ;
call insertEveniment();
```

You are using `drop procedure` statement with wrong delimiter (you were setting delimiter to  // but then you put ; at the end of your statement. Put your `drop procedure` statement before you set the delimiter, and it will work just fine. Also, put delimiters after `DECLARE`

Answer (score 0):

`DECLARE` is a separate statement, thus it needs to be delimited with a `;`, like `INSERT` or `SELECT` or any other statement.

Also, move the first `DELIMITER` statement to just before the beginning of the procedure declaration.

So,

```
DELIMITER //
drop procedure IF EXISTS insertEveniment;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE insertEveniment()
BEGIN
DECLARE vAdresaEvenimentId int DEFAULT 0 ;
insert into adresa(judet,localitate,codPostal,strada,nr,bl,ap,email,www) 
    values('judet','localitate','cod postal','strada','numar','bloc','ap','email','www');
select last_insert_id() into vAdresaEvenimentId;
DECLARE vEvenimentId int DEFAULT 0 ;
insert into eveniment(evenimentDenumire,adresaId) values('concurs informatic 1',vAdresaEvenimentId);
select last_insert_id() into vEvenimentId;
END //
DELIMITER ;
call insertEveniment();
```

Comment: if i do this place ; after  DECLARE i get this error  'ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE vEvenimentId int DEFAULT 0;'